# Java RegEx negative lookbehind

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following Java code:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<!function )\\w+");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("function example");
System.out.println(mat.find());
```

Why does `mat.find()` return true? I used negative lookbehind and `example` is preceded by `function`. Shouldn't it be discarded?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See what it matches:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<!function )\\w+");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher("function example");
    while (mat.find()) {
        System.out.println(mat.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
function
xample
```

So first it finds `function`, which isn't preceded by "`function`". Then it finds `xample` which is preceded by `function e` and therefore not "`function`".

Presumably you want the pattern to match the **whole** text, not just find matches *in* the text.

You can either do this with `Matcher.matches()` or you can change the pattern to add start and end anchors:

```
^(?<!function )\\w+$
```

I prefer the second approach as it means that the pattern itself defines its match region rather then the region being defined by its usage. That's just a matter of preference however.

Comment: I don't understand the solution adding the starting string anchor. Isn't that always going to return true, since the check is done at the beginning of the string and there's noway "function " is going to precede the starting string anchor? While `\\w` cannot possibly match the space, so nothing is found? It also doesn't find a match on "method example".

Comment: There’s also an end anchor @Scratte.

Comment: Yes. There is. How does that change anything? [It will only match a string of word characters. It doesn't check for function in the string itself](https://regex101.com/r/xOfomX/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your string has the word "function" that matches \w+, and is not preceded by "function ".

Answer (score 1):

Notice two things here:

- You're using `find()` which returns *true* for a *sub-string* match as well.
- Because of the above, "function" matches as it is not preceded by "function".
  The whole string would have never matched because your regex didn't
  include spaces.

Use `Mathcher#matches()` or `^` and `$` anchors with a negative lookahead instead:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^(?!function)[\\w\\s]+$"); // added \s for whitespaces
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("function example");

System.out.println(mat.find()); // false
```